# Type with members from a string array

Tags: typescript

Consider the following interface declaration:

```
interface Foo {
    bar(keys: string[], handler: (parameter: any) => void): void;
}
```

How can I represent that `parameter` of the handler is an object with members whose keys are in the `keys` array?

```
var x: Foo;
x.bar(['First', 'Second'], x => {
    console.log(x.First);
    console.log(x.Second);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

1. something that captures the string literals as a union of *string literal types* and
2. something that can take that union of literal types and create an object out of it.

(1) can be done with a type parameter (i.e. a generic) constrained to `string`, and (2) can be done with a mapped type - and it just so happens that TypeScript ships a mapped type called `Record<K, T>` with it:

```
interface Foo {
    bar<K extends string>(keys: K[], handler: (parameter: Record<K, any>) => void): void;
}

var x: Foo;
x.bar(['First', 'Second'], x => {
    console.log(x.First);
    console.log(x.);
});
```

[image]

Keep in mind, however, that if someone passes in an empty array or something other than a string literal (e.g. a variable of type `string`), then you'll get no type safety. You'll be able to access any property on `x`.

You can get around the empty array case by adding a generic default of `never` to say "infer the empty union instead of `string` when given an empty array":

```
interface Foo {
    bar<K extends string = never>(keys: K[], handler: (parameter: Record<K, any>) => void): void;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) to map each of the item in the array as key:

```
interface Foo {
    bar<T extends string>(keys: T[], handler: (parameter: {
        [P in T]: any
    }) => void): void;
}

var x: Foo;
x.bar(['First', 'Second'], x => {
    console.log(x.First);
    console.log(x.Second);
    console.log(x.Third); //error
});
```